# NSStream, NSError, error code

Tags: objective-c

I'm developing small FTP upload app. for mac (10.6 if it matters)

Have problem with NSStream, actually I cannot understand how to find our error by its code.

NSError code=14 domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain

Where to check what does 14 means?

Thank you.

Just in case here is my code (maybe you can also tell me why I have an error)

```
NSString *              filePath;
NSInputStream *         fStream;
NSStreamStatus *        status;
NSError *               error;  


filePath = @"/Users/Vic/Desktop/ftptest.txt";   
fStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath];
[fStream open];



uint8_t *         buffer;

NSInteger   bytesRead;

bytesRead = [fStream read:buffer maxLength:32768];

error = [fStream streamError];

NSLog(@"error code=%d domain=%@",error.code,error.domain);
```

Comment: I found the problem. Buffer should be defined as 
uint8_t buffer[32768];
and not * buffer; 

which is strange because that's how it's defined in official apple example (iPhone FTP)

anyway - I still can't get where to refer to check error codes.

Comment: The problem with the code is that you have not allocated a buffer, all you have done is declare a pointer *called* buffer but it doesn't point to anything. Using the array declaration fixes it because then buffer points to an array of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each domain has the error codes in a different place, but there's a summary in the [Error Handling Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH202-SW2). There's even a summary of some of the POSIX ones there. 14 is `EFAULT`.

Lots of times if you know the underlying system call you can view its man page to get more information about the error code. For instance in this case, you can invoke `man 2 read` from the terminal and it states:

> ```
>  [EFAULT]           Buf points outside the allocated address space.
> ```